# If $x represent column where x is 1..any what represents rows in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, xargs

Team, i need to know how to operate on value row wise after performing grep. I can operate column wise using $ but how to on row value?

my output is

```
cat file.txt | grep -o 'test1[^. ]*'
```

output:

```
test1-exam1-fail
test1-exam3-fail
test1-exam5-fail
```

Now with above output, i can use $1 to work on     test1-exam1-fail but what should i use to work on     test1-exam3-fail and also on exam5?

Answer (score 0):

Using paste command we can convert rows to columns

```
cat file.txt | grep -o 'test1[^. ]*' | paste - - -
```

so use - equal to columns we want.

Then we can operate on these values are $x where x = 1,2,3